# Upgraded my flutter sdk to the latest version. and when I click run button I found this error, is there anyone tell what is wrong with it?

Tags: android, flutter, entity-framework, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

Could not get unknown property 'upgrade' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Please share your build.gradle so we might be able to assist you

Comment: Check which flutter channel you're using, then go to github and open flutter's repo on a branch with the same name as channel, then go to examples, pick any example and open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and make sure you're using the same version. Also compare gradle plugin versions - it's in top-level `build.gradle` file inside of buildscript block

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326778/could-not-get-unknown-property-supportlibraryversion-for-object-of-type-org-gr

Comment: What are you trying to do?